# How to print off the joined RDD's result

Tags: scala, rdd

I have two RDDs:

```
scala> mgrMap.take(5).foreach(println)
(1,Cliff)
(2,Raj)
(3,Alim)
(4,Jose)
(5,Jeff)
```

and

```
salMap.take(5).foreach(println)
(1,100)
(2,200)
(3,300)
(4,400)
(5,500)
```

I joined them and have the third RDD:

```
scala> val joined = mgrMap.join(salMap)
scala> joined res14: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (String, Int))] = MapPartitionsRDD[8] at join at <console>:35
```

All I want is to print off the content of the third RDD "joined" as the format like:

```
(1, Cliff, 100)
....
(5, Jeff, 500)
```

I tried this and not working:

```
scala> val joinedMap = joined.map(x=>(x._1, x._2._1, x._2._2))
joinedMap: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String, Int)] = apPartitionsRDD[11] at map at <console>:37
```

When I do joinedMap.first, I got error of:

> 18/02/26 21:02:42 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 19.0
>   (TID 19) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

same error if I run

```
joined.collect
```

What's wrong in my command? How do I show the expected result from RDD like RDD[(Int, String, Int)]?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess you are getting error on some other lines of code. the code is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks but no, for the testing purpose I have only 5 lines data for each RDD

Comment: are you reading data from files ? the main cause I guess is that first element of one of the rdd tuple2 is string and the other is int. confirm that

Comment: code is working fine for me as well.

Comment: I finally identified the root cause which is like what Ramesh said. In the second RDD there is an extra blank line in the raw file which introduced a "" and it failed the joined result. Thank you all for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally identified the root cause which is what Ramesh said. In the second RDD there is an extra blank line in the raw file which introduced a "" and it failed the joined result. Thank you all for the replies.